# Как возможно через API TypeScript выполнить код TS в виде строки

Tags: javascript, typescript

Как возможно через API TypeScript выполнить код TS в виде строки
Тоесть как eval в js. С отлавливанием всех ошибок

Answer (score 0):

API компилятора TypeScript предоставляет способ преобразования исходных строк:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

let code: string = `({
    Run: (data: string): string => {
        console.log(data); return Promise.resolve("SUCCESS"); }
    })`;

let result = ts.transpile(code);
let runnalbe :any = eval(result);
runnalbe.Run("RUN!").then((result:string)=>{console.log(result);});
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153848/evaluate-typescript-from-string#answer-45156405) от участника [@Saravana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419531/saravana).</sub>

Comment: делал что-то такое, ошибок при выполнении не предоставляет

Comment: вообще выполнять код из строки - это отвратительно @SwedesJs